# Sphinx Dokumentation Viewer like Devhelp or QtAssistant

Tags: python-sphinx

Regarding a tool for "registering" documentations i came around Qt Assistant or Gtk DevHelp (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp). Both are supported as BUILDERS in Sphinx.

Is there any Project / Tool / Workflow that does the same for Sphinx Html Projects directly.
So just using searchindex and/or objects.inv from the html builds from Sphinx directly?

This would help in scenarios where documentation is splitted in several Projects / html directories and the user wants to quick search in all registered "Dokuments".

This does not necessary require to be an "app", it would be sufficient to have a html/js based solution to "search registered" documentations and open the corresponding html sites in the default system browser.

I expect this to work only local, i.e. like the above mentioned applications it should not register only sphinx documents, it should be used for local installed documentation html directories

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want software recommendations, ask here: [softwarerecs.se].